# Conditional formatting based on if/then on multiple fields

Tags: google-sheets

I want the background of a cell to be filled in based on one cell and then based on the number of days in the future, which are in other cells.

Cells A3 and A4 have a Date. 
Cells B3 and B4 will have text, either "Active" or "Potential"
Cells A10 to A12 are the number of days based on Active.
Cells A15 to A17 are the number of days based on Potential.

Based on the date in cell A3,​​ I want the format of cell A3 to be either red, yellow or green based on certain criteria. 
The first criteria is in Cell B3 which will have either "Active" or "Potential". 
If B3 says "Active" and the date ​​in A3 is the same as today, then I want cell A3 to be filled red.
If B3 says "Active" and the date in A3 is the same as tomorrow, then I want cell A3 to be filled yellow.
If B3 says "Active" and the date in A3 is after tomorrow, then I want cell A3 to be filled red.

If B3 says "Potential" and the date ​​in A3 is the same as today, then I want cell A3 to be filled red.
If B3 says "Potential" and the date in A3 is in 15 days or less from today, then I want cell A3 to be filled yellow.
If B3 says "Potential" and the date in A3 is greater than15 days from today, then I want cell A3 to be filled red.

I've been struggling to get this right. Any help would be much appreciated!! I pasted an image of my sheet below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot appears to be Google Sheets. As far as I am aware this type of advanced formatting is not available. I recommend using Excel instead.

Comment: It is Google Sheets. Actually, the formatting mostly works. The problem is that sometimes the cell ends up without any color at all (usually this is the bottom cell in the column), sometimes the wrong color appears (usually if the date is tomorrow, but other times too).